# Saving special characters in MySQL BLOB files

Tags: mysql, grails, utf-8

How to write special character (eastern europe languages) in MySQL BLOB field? I'm using UTF-8 everywhere (at least I think so). For regular string fields I'm getting valid values for cpecial characters, but for values in BLOB fields I get question mark.

Comment: Show some example queries, that might help. Blob fields are just data, so what you put in should be what you get out.

Comment: `BLOB` is a datatype for *binary*, not *character* data.  If you're storing text, use one of the character data types `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.  MySQL will then keep track of the character encoding and automatically perform any conversions to/from the encoding expected by your client: it won't do this with data in a binary type column such as `BLOB` (although you could explicitly [`CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) such data to a string using an explicit character encoding).