# Error encoding special characters

Tags: grails, utf-8, character-encoding

Bit of a strange problem (at least for me). In my Grails app I'm sending emails with some special characters (east European letters). Values of strings with special characters that I get from database are valid but the ones I create in application have "?".

Even more confusing is the fact that in development everything works fine, but when I deploy app to Tomcat instance I get the question marks.

I've set up everything to encode to UTF-8. At least I beleave so - obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735659 ?

Comment: @tim_yates No, it isn't.

Comment: Does it work if you display the files using the same font? Or one that covers that range of Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the operating system language 
packs installed for the languages you're trying to display.

While it appears as if the files themselves are saved properly, and the JVM 
'understands' them because the character sets are supported, the GUIs 
you're using can't display the corresponding encoding because the 
underlying OS isn't displaying them.

I've experienced similar problems and the solution that 
worked for me was to turn on the corresponding languages in the OS.

Comment: I dont think thats the problem. I'm guessing it's some Java, Grails or Tomcat setting. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: At some point its not recognizing the content that is why the ? is being displayed. It might not be the OS, it could be something with tomcat. But I didn't think tomcat has lang props. have you tried setting the language properties with the browser that you are using?